How Can You Explain Elements We Don't Have in our World?
I am creating a world in an alternative universe to ours, and I want to have unique elements and compounds with different properties than we have here. The thing is, I can't just plop these metals and gasses there without an explanation of why we don't have them in our world. We have discovered and studied virtually every useful combination of elements in our world, and know their molecular make-up.
What I want to do is create an additional aspect of an atom, independent of its structure, that depends on what universe it is in, that flips some of its secondary properties.
For example, an atom with 79 protons in our world (universe) is called Gold, and is very dense and malleable, but in another universe, an atom with the same atomic structure interacts differently due to this new characteristic.
This new characteristic of atoms would add a new dimension to the periodic table, giving it depth and making it really a bunch of parallel tables, one for each universe.
I would also like this new aspect to make an increasingly greater impact on the atoms' properties as the atomic number increases, so that carbon still exists as the basic building block, and people still breathe something similar to oxygen, and drink water-like molecules, but the metals farther down the table have completely different and interesting properties. I would also like materials to keep their properties as they are moved somehow between universes.
What could this factor be that changes it's properties based on what universe it originates from be?

Names are relatively arbitrary. As such there are far too many valid answers for this to be a suitable question for this site. Please also remember that we have a strict one question per post policy on this site.

I edited it. Is that acceptable?

If materials can be moved from one place to another, then both places are in the same universe by definition, because the universe is the totality of stuff than can interact with stuff. This does not mean that you cannot write an interesting story based on this idea; just call the relevant factor allognosticity or c(a)enotropy or whatever and run with it. But be self-aware that it has nothing to do with science.

You seem to be asking to brainstorm and create for you a whole system of additional physics in your world. That's far too broad a question to ask of us. Furthermore we are here to help you build your world by answering specific questions. Building your world for you by brainstorming or generating ideas is not permitted.

I'm unclear about what problem you're trying to solve. You have a great worldbuilding idea! Are you asking us to give you names for the elements? Are you asking us to create all those parallel periodic tables? What are you really stuck on? My biggest problem is the [tag:science-based] tag. There is no science for what you're talking about. Are you sure you want to use it? The [tag:science-fiction] tag (or no such tag) makes more sense to me.

@sphennings My bad, I misinterpreted the purpose of worldbuilding stack exchange. I will ask in a more relevant place. A science-fiction tag was absolutely what I intended, I just didn't realize it existed.

VTC. What you're essentially asking is to add a quantum number to existing physics. Not a bad thought, but there's no way to predict how the physics would work. When you flip spin, the results are defined by the laws of magnetism. When you flip charge, your results are defined by electricity. You can call your quantum number anything you want, but it's still magic, defined as a science we don't understand. Magic can be defined any way you want it to be.

Strange quarks.  They aren't terribly stable, even in your world, but they are very close in mass to down quarks.  Hadrons containing them break down slowly enough that the radioactivity is manageable, at least for organisms that are evolved to handle it.  As a result, many of your nuclei have a positive sigma in place of a proton.  I think the protons and neutrons would still tend to be equal in light elements, so effectively these would be a little lighter than the Earthly elements.  I would guess the chemistry should normally be similar, but the positive charge of the nucleus might be more concentrated ... there could be some subtle effect?  I'm curious to hear what others think there.
The obvious naming scheme is to add a prefix for how many positive sigmas are in a nucleus.  Ordinary lithium in our universe is monolithium.  Add a sigma+ in place of a proton and you have dilithium.  Replace another proton and you have trilithium.  Because the strange quarks are still just a wee bit higher energy, monolithium remains very common, but dilithium is also stable because you can have no more than two of each hadron in the nucleus (1 sigma+, 2 p+, 2n = 5dLi)  In agreement with rumors I've heard, dilithium is notable less for its chemical properties than for its effects in nuclear reactions.  I can't say I understand those well!

Wow. It looks we have a "friend" voted both of our answers down, who is not the OP. But I think such recreational quantum mechanics is useful and funny, maybe you think the same. As far I know, problem of strange quark matter is that if it would be stable, it would clog into SQM droplets and eat everything. But maybe a little manipulation of the higgs field could stabilize at least some of the strange nuclei.

Changing the nucleus doesn't affect chemistry much - different isotopes already have different masses but it's mostly impossible to separate them without a centrifuge. Perhaps you could replace the electrons with exotic particles instead? In the real world, muonic helium is helium-4 with a muon replacing one of the electrons. Since the muon stays close to the nucleus, only one electron is available for chemical interactions, so it behaves in many ways like an impossibly heavy (atomic mass 4.1) hydrogen atom.

@ChristopherWells Playing with muons in that way also makes transmutation of elements much easier — it’s far easier to swap a muon for an electron, or vice versa, than it is to add or subtract protons.

Mirror matter
Idea is that all particle has a pair exactly with the same properties, but without a way to interact with it. It is not antimatter.
The reason, why we can not interact with it, is that the mirror matter ejects/swallows mirror photons (gluons, weak bosons) and they do not interact with normal particles. There are only very few ways to interact with mirror matter. One of these is gravitation (mostly, out of reach) or some neutrinos (interacting very weakly).
Essentially, beside our normal world, we also have a "parallel dimension", a "mirror world". Unfortunately, just around us in the mirror world, there is only intergalactic space, this is why we could not find it until today.
However, a new discovery - maybe some manipulation of the Higgs field by weakly interacting Bose-Einstein-Condensates - makes possible for us to create bound states of matter - mirror matter particles.
For example, such a normal-mirror electron pair would look like an electron, but with double mass. It would have the funny property that it would look the same also in the mirror world!
Firstly, that would be a way to interact with the mirror matter. For example, using such pairs, we could build telescopes to watch the mirror universe.
Another important fact would be that all our particles would get a stable pair with double mass.

Its all about the electrons
The vast majority of qualities of any element are completely dependent on its electron configuration. Chemical bonds, color, conductivity, boiling temperatures... The notable exceptions being weight, and nuclear reactions which depend on the core components (protons, neutrons).
But for your everyday qualities, the electron is king; more specifically the Valence Electron. While number of protons "decides" how many electrons an atom can hold on to, there is another set of rules that decides how many valence electrons are available for each element.
Electron Configurations follow an octet rule and then a rule of 18. Essentially this is a determination of how many electrons are allowed on one shell before a new shell must be formed. In fact, the periodic table is specifically arranged with the configuration of the highest shell in mind. On the left are the most reactive alkali metals, which have an incomplete valence shell. On the right, the noble gasses that don't react with anything because their shells are full. But what really determines how many electrons are in each shell? It doesn't matter, you're gonna change it.
Now say for each universe your higher orbitals follow an 8 + 2n rule instead of the 18 rule (universe a is 10, b is 12, c is 14.. and we live in universe e). This would shift several of you elements around in the periodic table for each reality. Formerly reactive elements would behave like noble gases and have stable full shells, materials that were conductive will now have full shells and hold on greedily  to their electrons making insulators, mercury might be a solid at room temperature and another metal will take it's place, and so on and so forth.
Additionally, by modifying only the higher shells, the lighter elements would be left alone. So for your example of gold, it would still have the same number of protons, the same weight and could still be called gold. However, it's color, conductivity, boiling point, and all other properties that depend on electrochemistry would be drastically different.
